# NLTK synset with other languages

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, nltk

Right now i'm trying to compare words from two different files, one english, one chinese. I have to identify if any of the english words are related to the chinese words and if they are, are they equal or is one a hypernym of the other. I can use synsets for english but what can i do about the chinese words?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a Chinese (cmn) WordNet available from a university in Taiwan: http://casta-net.jp/~kuribayashi/multi/ . If this WordNet has the same format as the English WordNet, then you can probably use the WordNetCorpusReader (http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet-pysrc.html#WordNetCorpusReader) in NLTK to import the Mandarin data. I don't know how you're doing your alignments or translations between the two datasets, but assuming you can map English to Chinese, this should help you figure out how the relation between two English words compares to the relation between two Mandarin words. Note that if your data uses the simplified script, you may also need to convert to the traditional script before using this cmn WordNet.

Comment: ;P the `Open Multilingual WordNet` is a great resource for non-english wordnet, and if ANYONE is glad to code the NLTK API, do contact Francis Bond @ http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/fcbond/ or Steven Bird http://ww2.cs.mu.oz.au/~sb/ or both =)

Comment: That would be why I linked to the full list rather than just the WordNet OP needed. I should add something to mention how the ontologies developed for different languages aren't typically identical cross-linguistically, though I think for hypo- and hyper-nym identification the hierarchical structure might be close enough in many cases.

Comment: it is possible to have language independent domain specific ontologies but i don't think hypo/hypernym hierachies are that close crosslingually. See http://goo.gl/LkN3h